# Making a Mongo movie DB with a several fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Newbie here - I am making a denormalized movie database with many fields (i.e. columns) - such as title, date, genre, budget per movie... I want to add many more fields - like possibly as much as 70 more...! I am currently thinking of using Mongodb because of it's speed - however, I know that mongodb is non relational --- here are my questions:

1. Does that mean I will have one giant collection (I know there is a `lookup` mongodb function - but I don't understand why anybody would use that - because in essence, wouldn't you just do a sql db at that point (and not mongo)?
2. What is the limit in how many fields I can have in a Mongo db?
3. Open book here - if you have any other suggestions on the what kind of db / how I should set this up - let me know.  Please note, I am using node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding #1: Yes, one big collection is the way to go. Do *not* use `lookup` unless there is absolutely no other way, as the whole aggregation framework is just a slow crutch to deal with bad database design. For MongoDB, don't ask yourself how you *store* things, ask yourself how you *query* things. For basically making a list and detail-view of movies, one collection is best (using indexes on common search fields, maybe a full text index, a small number of projected fields for the overview lists.)

Regarding #2: There is no limit to the number, but to the document size: one single document is limited to 16 MB. As long as we are talking about text, this should usually be enough for all practical purposes.

More thoughts for #3: 
If you have something like a reference to actors: put a subset of the "Actor" object which is needed while displaying the movie information into the movie object, so that you only need to query that single movie for the whole detail view. If the user clicks on that actor, you can still open a detail view and use a separate query on the actor collection to display the actor's details.

Comment: Thank you - this helps a lot.  I have one follow up question - when you stated "put a subset of the 'Actor'" object - did you mean define the schema type as `map` for Actor so I can have sub fields?

Comment: @dlearns  Frankly, I don't know how you define schemas in mongoose (as defining a schema in a schemaless database is somewhat convoluted anyway). From the database perspective, it should be an array of sub-documents.